# Given a list of tuples, check to see if it's possible to construct a word in which the second value in the tuple is not consecutively repeated

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

Let's say I have a list of tuples like so:

```
list_of_tuples = [('A', 'R'), ('B', 'R'), ('C', 'G'), ('D', 'G'), ('E', 'B'), ('D', 'B'), ('R', 'B'), ('F', 'R'), ('V', 'R'), ('A', 'G')]
```

The second value in each tuple will always either be `R`, `B`, or `G`. I'd like to create a function `validate` that checks to see if a certain word can be constructed using the letters in the first position of each tuple, but only if the letters in the section position of that tuple are not repeated.

For example, it's possible to construct the word:

`ACE` with `(A, R)`, `(C, G)` and `(E, B)` since the second value in each tuple corresponds to `RGB` which doesn't repeat any letter consecutively.

`ACED` with `(A, R), (C, G), (E, B), and ('D', 'B')` is not possible since that would correspond to `RGBB` in which there is a consecutive B.

Note that sometimes the same letter can have different letter in its second position, for example:

`('A', 'R') and ('A', 'G')`. You'd only be able to spell `ACE` if you selected the first tuple, not the second, otherwise the `G`'s would repeat.

Also note that combinations like `GBRBG` are possible even though the second position letters "repeat" they don't repeat consecutively.

So I'd like a function that can validate words in the following way:

`def validate(submitted_word, list_of_tuples)`

One possibility is to construct every possible combination of sequences that are possible with this set and the corresponding sequences that would be produced with the letters in the second sequence, filter out the ones that are valid words, and then filter out the ones that have consecutive repeats of letters, but I worry that will be to inefficient given how big the list of tuples can become.

Comment: Should the solution be optimised to work with several queries using the same `list_of_tuples`, or are the calls to `validate` typically independent, and using different values for both arguments?

Comment: Is it allowed to use a tuple more than once for the same word (when it has multiple occurrences of the same letter)?

Comment: The calls to `validate` will be independent using different lists of tuples each time. And no, the moment you use a tuple for a given word, that tuple is used up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below for a self-contained solution and tests:

```py
list_of_tuples = [
    ('A', 'R'),
    ('B', 'R'),
    ('C', 'G'),
    ('D', 'G'),
    ('E', 'B'),
    ('D', 'B'),
    ('R', 'B'),
    ('F', 'R'),
    ('V', 'R'),
    ('A', 'G')
]

def validate(submitted_word, list_of_tuples):
    # Check length of word
    if len(submitted_word) == 0:
        raise ValueError("len(submitted_word) must be > 0")

    # Initialise options for first character
    options = [[tup for tup in list_of_tuples if tup[0] == submitted_word[0]]]
    # Iterate through the rest of the characters
    for char in submitted_word[1:]:
        # Initialise set of characters in second position of previous tuple
        forbidden_chars = set(tup[1] for tup in options[-1])
        # Add valid options for the next character
        options.append([
            tup
            for tup in list_of_tuples
            if (tup[0] == char) and len(forbidden_chars - set(tup[1])) > 0
        ])
        # If there are no options, then submitted_word does not validate
        if len(options[-1]) == 0:
            print(options)
            return False
    
    print(options)
    return True

print(validate("ACE", list_of_tuples))
print()
print(validate("ACED", list_of_tuples))
print()
print(validate("ACFFFED", list_of_tuples))
```

Console output:

```
[[('A', 'R'), ('A', 'G')], [('C', 'G')], [('E', 'B')]]
True

[[('A', 'R'), ('A', 'G')], [('C', 'G')], [('E', 'B')], [('D', 'G')]]        
True

[[('A', 'R'), ('A', 'G')], [('C', 'G')], [('F', 'R')], []]
False
```

Comment: I really enjoyed going through this code and learned a lot. I thought the `len(forbidden_chars - set(tup[1])) > 0` line in particular was very clever. Very clear and straightforward. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph traversal problem.  Your available nodes are the tuples of (letter, color); your edges are the letter transitions in the given word.

For each input, "simply" construct the graph for that word.  Given ACE, you have

```
Layer 1 -- transition START to any A
START -> AR
START -> AG

Layer 2 -- transition A to C
AR -> CG
not allowed: AG -> CG

Layer 3 -- transition C to E
CG -> EB

Layer 4 -- transition any E to GOAL
EB -> GOAL
```

Now you simply apply the graph traversal function (any self-respecting graph package has one) to solve your spelling problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can use backtracking, where the state is the count of each of R, G, B used per letter, as well as the previous "RGB" chosen, as we construct the word.

Python code (not memoized):

```
def f(i, word, prev, state):
  if i == len(word):
    return True

  letter = word[i]

  for second in ["R", "G", "B"]:
    if state[letter][second] and prev != second:
      state[letter][second] -= 1
      is_valid = f(i + 1, word, second, state)
      state[letter][second] += 1
      if is_valid:
        return True

  return False

def get_counts(tuples):
  result = {}
  for letter, rgb in tuples:
    if letter in result:
      result[letter][rgb] += 1
    else:
      result[letter] = {"R": 0, "G": 0, "B": 0}
      result[letter][rgb] = 1
  return result

tuples = [('A', 'R'), ('B', 'R'), ('C', 'G'), ('D', 'G'), ('E', 'B'), ('D', 'B'), ('R', 'B'), ('F', 'R'), ('V', 'R'), ('A', 'G')]

counts = get_counts(tuples)

print f(0, "ACE", "", counts) # True
print f(0, "ACED", "", counts) # True
print f(0, "BF", "", counts) # False
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Slowly moving through this code trying to understand it. I've never seen the `|=` operator before. Does this form a union?

Comment: @Parseltongue |= means OR equals, in the same sense as += means PLUS equals. So if we have a boolean that's already True, either True or False on the right won't change it. But if we start out with False, only by |= True can we change it to True.

Comment: Parseltongue the code is basically trying all relevant states, which can be idiosyncratic depending on the input. Obviously, we can only continue to build the word if the state contains at least one count of the letter at index `i` of the word. I assume you understand the get_counts function.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. That's clever. Yes, I understood the get_counts function. Thanks so much, I believe I understand now.

Comment: @Parseltongue I changed the algorithm to recursive backtracking with a single `counts` object for state.

Answer (score 0):

I built the following. Firstly we create a function that compares 2 lists and checks if they have at least one different element. Secondly we run this function for the assosiated lists of all consecutive pairs of letters in the word. I considered that all letters of the word are represented in the list_of_tuples. Otherwise it will need a couple of lines more to check for existance (let me know in that case, so that i will add them).

```
def validate(word, list_of_tuples):
    def rgb(l1,l2):
        return len(set(l1).difference(set(l2)))>0

l=[[i, [k[1] for k in list_of_tuples if k[0]==i]] for i in word]

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if not rgb(l[i][1], l[i+1][1]):
        return False
return True
```

Comment: Please explain the algorithm.

Comment: I will update the answer, as it doesn't fully covers the question